# Should I call dns_get_record() multiple times, or once with DNS_ANY?

Tags: php

For the PHP function [dns_get_record()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php), does using `DNS_ANY` to fetch all records make more or less http (or whatever protocol) requests than calling the types individually?

```
// Is just 1 request? Or many requests (1 per each record type)?
dns_get_record('example.com', DNS_ANY);

VS

// 3 total requests?
dns_get_record('example.com', DNS_A);
dns_get_record('example.com', DNS_AAAA);
dns_get_record('example.com', DNS_MX);
```

Basically, I would like to minimize network requests if I can, but I have no idea how dns_get_record() works under the hood.

Since the documentation says that `DNS_ANY` doesn't always return all records, I figured I could try calling the types I want individually to get more predictable results. But doing so makes 3 individual requests vs one request with DNS_ANY. Is this true?

Btw, `DNS_ALL` or `DNS_A + DNS_AAAA + DNS_MX` will return false if any of the types are null, so I can't do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetching the info individually for each type is inefficient since that would involve multiple requests, whereas using the DNS_ANY parameter with dns_get_record(), gets all the information in just one request.  The DNS_ANY is a parameter that is handy for querying the dns server for info.  With this particular parameter, you may get quite a bit of info.

You can see this yourself if you try using a utility such as "dig" at a Linux commandline prompt for a domain like gmail.com, as follows:

`dig gmail.com ANY`

The output is as follows:

```
`;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.                     IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.              2386    IN      MX      30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.c                                                                              om.
gmail.com.              2386    IN      MX      40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.c                                                                              om.
gmail.com.              2386    IN      MX      5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              2386    IN      MX      10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.c                                                                              om.
gmail.com.              2386    IN      MX      20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.c                                                                              om.
gmail.com.              85186   IN      SOA     ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google                                                                              .com. 2012061200 21600 3600 1209600 300
gmail.com.              81180   IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
gmail.com.              81180   IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
gmail.com.              81180   IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
gmail.com.              81180   IN      NS      ns2.google.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
gmail.com.              81180   IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
gmail.com.              81180   IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
gmail.com.              81180   IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
gmail.com.              81180   IN      NS      ns1.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.         223708  IN      A       216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.         223708  IN      A       216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.         223708  IN      A       216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.         223708  IN      A       216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 4 msec
[snip]
```

PHP's dns_get_record() behaves like the dig utility, i.e. it contacts the dns server and performs a query. A parameter like "DNS_ANY" is advantageous since it gets everything all at once.  Since "dig" took 4 msec, I assume dns_get_record() would take approximately as long or maybe slightly longer.  Since the DNS_ANY parameter might yield more info than one may require, one may, for example, restrict that query to just "MX" records by using DNS_MX with the function.

If you're curious about PHP's internal source code for this function, look [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/standard/dns.c#752). The internal source code is generally written in the C Programming Language.

If you want to know more about how the dns system works, especially when using PHP, see my article for php|architect entitled "Email Verification" (June 2008).